# How to find the axis of rotation needed to rotate a $ 3d$ vector to another $3d$ vector?

Tags: vector-spaces, rotations

I have two vectors $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$. How can I find the axis of rotation needed to rotate the first vector to be parallel to the other vector?

Thanks

Comment: This has been answered here [rotation][1].


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81017/vector-rotation-in-3d

Comment: and also in your [previous, closely related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/735136/29335)